# Inconsistent Performance Issue with ORDER BY Query

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, indexing

I have a Django app which is connected to a PostgreSQL 9.1.9 database running on its own dedicated machine with 2gb of RAM. The database stores a cache of Twitter tweets (about 1 million of them), and indexes them based on the words they contain. Here are the 2 relevant models:

```
class TwitterPassage(models.Model):
    third_party_id = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN, db_index=True, unique=True)
    third_party_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_index=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN)
    words = models.ManyToManyField('connectr.Word')
    quality = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    author_fk = models.ForeignKey('connectr.TwitterUser', null=True)

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN, db_index=True, unique=True)
    display_word = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN, default='', blank=True)
    passage_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_index=True, blank=True)

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=STANDARD_MAX_LEN, db_index=True)
    tweet_passages = models.ManyToManyField('connectr.TwitterPassage', through='connectr.PassageViewEvent')
```

Word has a many to many relationship with any TwitterPassage that contains that word.

The query I run is:

```
# Exclude tweets this user has already seen, and find the 20 highest quality tweets they haven't yet seen
word.twitterpassage_set.exclude(user=current_user).order_by('-quality')[:20]
```

Quality is an integer score that ranges from about 0 to 300.

What happens is, sometimes this query is fast like I need it to be (under a second). But other times, it is painfully slow - up to 10 seconds. It seems to work especially well for words that are really common, like "their" or "my", and not so well for rare words connected to fewer TwitterPassages.

I have 8 fields indexed of the TwitterPassage model, and 5 of the Word model. Is this just a sign that I need more RAM or fewer indexes? How would I go about figuring out which of these might fix the issue?

Also if it helps, here is some info about the DB size:

```
                            relation                                |  size   
------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_words_word_id                           | 1680 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_twitterpassage_id_613c80271f09fba8_uniq | 1199 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_words_pkey                              | 1010 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_words                                   | 1009 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_words_twitterpassage_id                 | 1002 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage                                         | 620 MB
 public.connectr_twitteruser                                            | 449 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_created                                 | 256 MB
 public.connectr_passage_source_like                                    | 230 MB
 public.connectr_passage_source                                         | 229 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_is_top_tweet                            | 194 MB
 public.connectr_passage_pkey                                           | 187 MB
 public.connectr_word                                                   | 184 MB
 public.connectr_passage_third_party_id_like                            | 181 MB
 public.connectr_passage_third_party_id                                 | 180 MB
 public.connectr_passage_retweet_count                                  | 170 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_third_party_id_uniq                     | 168 MB
 public.connectr_passage_favorited_count                                | 166 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_quality                                 | 159 MB
 public.connectr_twitterpassage_author_fk_id                            | 118 MB
```

EDIT: Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query, per Jakub's suggestion:

```
 Limit  (cost=37918.71..37918.72 rows=20 width=204) (actual time=1495.133..1495.201 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=37918.71..37919.01 rows=606 width=204) (actual time=1495.129..1495.156 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: connectr_twitterpassage.quality
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 24kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.35..37915.49 rows=606 width=204) (actual time=0.301..1485.234 rows=1249 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using connectr_twitterpassage_words_word_id on connectr_twitterpassage_words  (cost=0.00..4905.80 rows=1212 width=4) (actual time=0.091..812.018 rows=1249 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (word_id = 18890456)
               ->  Index Scan using connectr_passage_pkey on connectr_twitterpassage  (cost=18.35..27.23 rows=1 width=204) (actual time=0.515..0.525 rows=1 loops=1249)
                     Index Cond: (id = connectr_twitterpassage_words.twitterpassage_id)
                     Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) OR (id IS NULL))
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Index Scan using connectr_passageviewevent_user_id on connectr_passageviewevent u1  (cost=0.00..18.34 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.033..0.091 rows=5 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
                             Filter: (passage_id IS NOT NULL)
 Total runtime: 1495.700 ms
(15 rows)
```

After running the above query for several different words, some words were very fast (~200ms), and others much slower (~1500ms or more). If I run the same query more than once, the second time it is much faster (I guess it's cached?).

Here are the table definitions:

```
                                       Table "public.connectr_word"
       Column        |           Type           |                         Modifiers                          
---------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer                  | not null default nextval('connectr_word_id_seq'::regclass)
 word                | character varying(10000) | not null
 created             | timestamp with time zone | not null
 modified            | timestamp with time zone | not null
 frequency           | double precision         | 
 is_username         | boolean                  | not null
 is_hashtag          | boolean                  | not null
 cloud_eligible      | boolean                  | not null
 passage_count       | integer                  | 
 avg_quality         | double precision         | 
 last_twitter_search | timestamp with time zone | 
 cloud_approved      | boolean                  | not null
 display_word        | character varying(10000) | not null
 is_trend            | boolean                  | not null
Indexes:
    "connectr_word_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "connectr_word_word_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (word)
    "connectr_word_avg_quality" btree (avg_quality)
    "connectr_word_cloud_eligible" btree (cloud_eligible)
    "connectr_word_last_twitter_search" btree (last_twitter_search)
    "connectr_word_passage_count" btree (passage_count)
    "connectr_word_word" btree (word)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "connectr_passageviewevent" CONSTRAINT "source_word_id_refs_id_178d46eb" FOREIGN KEY (source_word_id) REFERENCES connectr_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_wordmatchrewardevent" CONSTRAINT "tapped_word_id_refs_id_c2ffb369" FOREIGN KEY (tapped_word_id) REFERENCES connectr_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_connection" CONSTRAINT "word_id_refs_id_00cccde2" FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES connectr_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_twitterpassage_words" CONSTRAINT "word_id_refs_id_64f49629" FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES connectr_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED


                                         Table "public.connectr_twitterpassage"
         Column         |           Type           |                              Modifiers                               
------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                  | not null default nextval('connectr_twitterpassage_id_seq'::regclass)
 third_party_id         | character varying(10000) | not null
 source                 | character varying(10000) | not null
 text                   | character varying(10000) | not null
 author                 | character varying(10000) | not null
 raw_data               | character varying(10000) | not null
 created                | timestamp with time zone | not null
 modified               | timestamp with time zone | not null
 third_party_created    | timestamp with time zone | 
 retweet_count          | integer                  | not null
 favorited_count        | integer                  | not null
 lang                   | character varying(10000) | not null
 location               | character varying(10000) | not null
 author_followers_count | integer                  | not null
 is_retweet             | boolean                  | not null
 url                    | character varying(10000) | not null
 author_fk_id           | integer                  | 
 quality                | bigint                   | 
 is_top_tweet           | boolean                  | not null
Indexes:
    "connectr_passage_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_third_party_id_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (third_party_id)
    "connectr_passage_author_followers_count" btree (author_followers_count)
    "connectr_passage_favorited_count" btree (favorited_count)
    "connectr_passage_retweet_count" btree (retweet_count)
    "connectr_passage_source" btree (source)
    "connectr_passage_source_like" btree (source varchar_pattern_ops)
    "connectr_passage_third_party_id" btree (third_party_id)
    "connectr_passage_third_party_id_like" btree (third_party_id varchar_pattern_ops)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_author_fk_id" btree (author_fk_id)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_created" btree (created)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_is_top_tweet" btree (is_top_tweet)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_quality" btree (quality)
    "connectr_twitterpassage_third_party_created" btree (third_party_created)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "author_fk_id_refs_id_074720a5" FOREIGN KEY (author_fk_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitteruser(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "connectr_passageviewevent" CONSTRAINT "passage_id_refs_id_892b36a6" FOREIGN KEY (passage_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitterpassage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_connection" CONSTRAINT "twitter_from_id_refs_id_8adbab24" FOREIGN KEY (twitter_from_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitterpassage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_connection" CONSTRAINT "twitter_to_id_refs_id_8adbab24" FOREIGN KEY (twitter_to_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitterpassage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_twitterpassage_words" CONSTRAINT "twitterpassage_id_refs_id_720f772f" FOREIGN KEY (twitterpassage_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitterpassage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED


                                           Table "public.connectr_user"
           Column           |           Type           |                         Modifiers                          
----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id                         | integer                  | not null default nextval('connectr_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id                    | character varying(10000) | not null
 reference_name             | character varying(10000) | not null
 created                    | timestamp with time zone | 
 modified                   | timestamp with time zone | 
 score                      | integer                  | not null
 twitter_screen_name        | character varying(10000) | not null
 twitter_oauth_token        | character varying(10000) | not null
 twitter_oauth_token_secret | character varying(10000) | not null
 twitter_keys_last_used     | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "connectr_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "connectr_user_score" btree (score)
    "connectr_user_user_id" btree (user_id)
    "connectr_user_user_id_like" btree (user_id varchar_pattern_ops)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "connectr_connection" CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_366cf6e8" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_passageviewevent" CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_478f94a2" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_user_reddit_passages" CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_488fdfea" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_wordmatchrewardevent" CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_8a36f38a" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "connectr_user_book_passages" CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_e830956b" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

                                      Table "public.connectr_passageviewevent"
     Column     |           Type           |                               Modifiers                                
----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('connectr_passageviewevent_id_seq'::regclass)
 passage_id     | integer                  | not null
 user_id        | integer                  | not null
 source_word_id | integer                  | not null
 next_id        | integer                  | 
 connection_id  | integer                  | 
 date           | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "connectr_passageviewevent_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_connection_id" btree (connection_id)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_date" btree (date)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_next_id" btree (next_id)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_passage_id" btree (passage_id)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_source_word_id" btree (source_word_id)
    "connectr_passageviewevent_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "connection_id_refs_id_a3ff7fc2" FOREIGN KEY (connection_id) REFERENCES connectr_connection(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "next_id_refs_id_f737727c" FOREIGN KEY (next_id) REFERENCES connectr_passageviewevent(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "passage_id_refs_id_892b36a6" FOREIGN KEY (passage_id) REFERENCES connectr_twitterpassage(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "source_word_id_refs_id_178d46eb" FOREIGN KEY (source_word_id) REFERENCES connectr_word(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "user_id_refs_id_478f94a2" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES connectr_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "connectr_passageviewevent" CONSTRAINT "next_id_refs_id_f737727c" FOREIGN KEY (next_id) REFERENCES connectr_passageviewevent(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

And here is the raw SQL of the query which is (sometimes) slow (generated by Django):

```
SELECT "connectr_twitterpassage"."id", "connectr_twitterpassage"."third_party_id", "connectr_twitterpassage"."third_party_created", "connectr_twitterpassage"."source", "connectr_twitterpassage"."text", "connectr_twitterpassage"."author", "connectr_twitterpassage"."raw_data", "connectr_twitterpassage"."retweet_count", "connectr_twitterpassage"."favorited_count", "connectr_twitterpassage"."lang", "connectr_twitterpassage"."location", "connectr_twitterpassage"."author_followers_count", "connectr_twitterpassage"."is_retweet", "connectr_twitterpassage"."url", "connectr_twitterpassage"."author_fk_id", "connectr_twitterpassage"."quality", "connectr_twitterpassage"."is_top_tweet", "connectr_twitterpassage"."created", "connectr_twitterpassage"."modified" 
    FROM "connectr_twitterpassage" INNER JOIN "connectr_twitterpassage_words" 
    ON ("connectr_twitterpassage"."id" = "connectr_twitterpassage_words"."twitterpassage_id") 
    WHERE ("connectr_twitterpassage_words"."word_id" = 19514309  
    AND NOT (("connectr_twitterpassage"."id" 
    IN (SELECT U1."passage_id" FROM "connectr_passageviewevent" U1 WHERE (U1."user_id" = 1  AND U1."passage_id" IS NOT NULL)) AND "connectr_twitterpassage"."id" IS NOT NULL))) 
    ORDER BY "connectr_twitterpassage"."quality" DESC LIMIT 20
```

After adding these indexes:

```
create index word_to_twitterpassage_id on connectr_twitterpassage_words (word_id,twitterpassage_id);
create index id_to_quality_sorted on connectr_twitterpassage (id,quality desc nulls last);
```

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE is now this:

```
 Limit  (cost=34679.26..34679.31 rows=20 width=206) (actual time=7.883..7.887 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=34679.26..34681.02 rows=704 width=206) (actual time=7.882..7.884 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: connectr_twitterpassage.quality
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=16.86..34660.53 rows=704 width=206) (actual time=2.669..7.618 rows=102 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using word_to_twitterpassage_id on connectr_twitterpassage_words  (cost=0.00..67.21 rows=1408 width=4) (actual time=2.493..3.094 rows=102 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (word_id = 18860699)
                     Heap Fetches: 1
               ->  Index Scan using connectr_passage_pkey on connectr_twitterpassage  (cost=16.86..24.56 rows=1 width=206) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=102)
                     Index Cond: (id = connectr_twitterpassage_words.twitterpassage_id)
                     Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) OR (id IS NULL))
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on connectr_passageviewevent u1  (cost=4.46..16.80 rows=27 width=4) (actual time=0.049..0.066 rows=25 loops=1)
                             Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1)
                             Filter: (passage_id IS NOT NULL)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on connectr_passageviewevent_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.45 rows=27 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=26 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
 Total runtime: 8.042 ms
(18 rows)
```

Comment: Sounds like you should start indexing these tweets in a search engine or start caching searches in your app.

Comment: If you need the top 20, it should be `[:20]` and not `[20]`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo when I added it here.

Comment: Indexes don't speed up the query just because you have a certain number of them. It's hard to tell if your indexes are correct if we can't see them, can't see the actual query and can't see the `EXPLAIN` of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the EXPLAIN statement.

Comment: The nested loop over two index scans indicates that there are some FKs or indexes missing. Please add the table definitions and the plain SQL of the query to the question (the django stuff is barely readable for hardcore DBA's)

Comment: +1 what joop said. Show how the sql defs, sql query, and how the plans differ between a fast and a slow query in the question.

Comment: OK, added the raw SQL and table definitions.

Comment: Could you try creating two indexes? First on `connectr_twitterpassage_words (word_id, twitterpassage_id)` and second on `connectr_twitterpassage(id,quality)`. Please, create both and post `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` again.

Comment: I added two indexes based on Matheus's suggestion: create index word_to_twitterpassage_id on connectr_twitterpassage_words (word_id,twitterpassage_id); and create index id_to_quality_sorted on connectr_twitterpassage (id,quality desc nulls last); With these 2 the performance is MUCH better. Under 200 MS. I'd say problem solved. Much thanks!

Comment: I'd like to clarify why it made it better on an answer, and also check if those were the best ones. Could you send the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and the indexes names?

Comment: Ok I added the EXPLAIN ANALYZE to the question. If you want to experiment with it a bit, I can send you the credentials for my dev VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, your issue was caused by missing foreign keyindexes causing a nested loop join based on other criteria.  Adding these indexes solved your problem.

In general in PostgreSQL you should always index all foreign keys (primary keys and unique fields are automatically indexed) on any non-trivially sized tables and then add whatever other indexes you really need.  In this case you were missing foreign key indexes.